# javascript equivalent of union in c

Tags: javascript

I wonder if there is an equivalent of c/++ union in Javascript? I need to use it as a library I use for an Html5 game wants some fixed variable names for the object I pass to a function of this library however it is much easier for me to keep the data in an array for easier calculation.
To give an example, say there is a function 'F' in the library which takes a transformation matrix as a parameter. The parameter must have variable names 'a', 'b', ... 'f' which correspond to matrix elements(m[0][0], m[0][1] ...) consecutively. I have my own matrix class for calculations in which I use an array.
I know that entering the parameter 'on the fly', as shown below, sorts out my problem however I don't want to do that every time I call the function nor I want to write a proxy function.

```
F({a:m[0][0], b:m[0][1], c:[0][2], d:m[1][0], e:m[1][1], f:[1][2]});
```

is there any way around that such as union?

Comment: Can you maybe show an example of what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there's not.

Answer (score 2):

There is no concept of a union, but since the language is loosely-typed you should never need anything of the sort.

You can change the type that is in a variable on the fly (and of course you can use an object with properties which are also loosely typed).

Comment: Exactly. Unions work around a problem JavaScript doesn't have.